# Twitter API getting follower ids for huge number, without getting error

Tags: python, ruby, twitter, mysql-python

[I am using Python, and ruby gem twurl to request with OAuth.]

I am trying to get follower ids from Twitter, for @BarackObama, who has 24,265,751 followers currently.
Mathematically, 24,265,751 /5000/350 gives 13.8 hrs to collect, and that is about 14-15 hrs if we give it with an hour margin.

Everytime I try to collect it with my code, it gives error on some point while pagination.
When I get back on collecting after I get error, it looks at different page so that it collects more than I was expected to have.

I want to know if I am working wrong, or my code architecture has defects.
Here are my functions to use;

```
def request_followers(namevar, name, candidate_id, id_str):
    next_cursor = -1
    cmd = 'twurl "/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=' + namevar + '"'
    data = fol_req(cmd)

    /*code to add data into database as soon as it gets the data.*/

    try:
        if (data.get('ids')):
        while (len(data.get('ids')) == 5000):
        next_cursor = data['next_cursor']
        followers_request = 'twurl "/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=' + str(next_cursor) + '&screen_name=' + namevar+'"'
        try:
            data = fol_req(followers_request)
            /*code to add data into database as soon as it gets the data.*/
            except:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue # if error, retry after 5 sec.
    except:
        print "error on", followers_request
        check_list.append(followers_request)
```

This is to have pagination, and

```
def fol_req(followers_request):
    request_limit = remainingHits()
    attempt = 0
    data = {}
    while (attempt < request_limit-1) and not(data.get('ids')):
        try:
            attempt += 1
            (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(followers_request)
            if status:
                sys.stderr.write(output)
                sys.exit(1)
            data = json.loads(output)
        except:
            continue
        break
    else:
        request_limit = remainingHits()
        time.sleep(1200)
        data = fol_req(followers_request)   
    return data
```

This is to request using twurl and python sys.

Is my architecture wrong some point?

Comment: I would be surprised if the service allows you to freely fetch that amount of data. Do they legally allow that ?

Comment: You're probably hitting the limits of Twitter api. It shouldn't let you do more than 150 calls.